# phpMyAdmin - Show BLOB fields as text?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was wondering why in phpMyAdmin I see something like this:

```
**Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete [BLOB - 7B] [BLOB - 32B]    [BLOB - 13B]    [BLOB - 16B]**
```

Why can't I see the actual text? When I click `[BLOB-/nx/]`, I just get prompted to download a .BIN file.

I tried adding:

```
$cfg['ShowBlob']              = true;
```

To `phpMYAdmin/config.inc.php`, but it didn't work. I have also tried adding to the URL `&display_blob=true`.

I am trying to do this on localhost with XAMPP by the way.

My version of phpMyAdmin is 3.4.5, if it's needed.

Answer (score 45):

phpMyAdmin has an "+option" link on top of each result set. Click it, and you will see the option to display blob contents.

I should add: some phpMyAdmin versions have a bug where the "+option" link does not show up on the first load of the results, you need to click [ Refresh ] to make it appear.

Comment: @sackbot14 No problem. Blob content can be tricky to deal with ;)

Comment: Thanks Novo :) I upgraded my DB from latin1 to utf8 , after all utf8 fields are showed as BLOB . Now I can see the content

Comment: Thanks, any way to display it by default?

Comment: There is an option in newer versions to always display the index table.

Answer (score 4):

In PHPMyAdmin, there is a `+Options` above the results table. To show the blob contents:

1. Click `+Options`

[image]

2. Then click `Show Blob contents` and press `Go` to save.

[image]

Then, in order to enable the Blob columns to be editable:

1. Go to `Settings` > `Main Panel` > `Edit Mode`
2. In the row `Protect Binary Columns`, click on the right dropdown menu and select `no`.
3. Press `Apply` to save.

[image]