# Why does imported MySQL dump show some column value as BLOB?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I imported a MySQL table dump from my server to my local system. I am using phpMyAdmin to view my local MySQL databases. The column that held emails shows as BLOB -  instead of actual email.

When I press on "edit" it shows correct emails, but not on listing.

I am totally confused as why this happens. Can anyone suggest solution?

Answer (score 1):

BLOB data type is meant to store arbitrary binary data (Binary Large OBject = BLOB), for example an image or another document. It does not make sense to show the value as-is. It would look the same as viewing an image in a text editor.

You have several options, depending on the version of phpMyAdmin you are using - which I unfortunately do not know.

- Make phpMyAdmin show BLOB values by default.
- Show BLOB values for a complete result set.

These two possibilities are covered by [an already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762956/phpmyadmin-show-blob-fields-as-text).

But basically, this is just fighting symptoms instead of curing the disease. The question is: Why did you chose the email field to be a BLOB? Basically, a VARCHAR is enough. I do not know the MySQL version you are running, but since MySQL 5.0.3, a VARCHAR can be [as large as 65k byte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).

```
ALTER TABLE
  `table`
CHANGE
  `email` `email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

The query above changes the field `email` to a VARCHAR(255). Pay attention to the length you like to use, and to the character set and collation. But UTF-8 should be very fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the text of "Blob" as a placeholder as the blob datatype (which is the datatype that your emails are stored in) is vastly variable in size. For large Blob sizes, if the data were displayed, it could take up 100s + screens to display.