# AES_Decrypt() returning null value

Tags: mysql, sql, aes, mariadb

SQL-Newbie here. I'm working with a table that contains data (of the `longblob` type), which looks like this (imported into phpMyAdmin):

[image: table1]

These files are (apperently) AES encrypted using `AES_Encrypt()` . I know the key to the file with the key-id 2332, and I want to call `AES_Decrypt()` on that "blahb" (blob). For this, I wrote a procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE dat longblob;
    SELECT blahb into dat from fyle where keeid = p_id;
    SELECT AES_Decrypt(dat, p_key) into p_out;
END
```

And embedded it intp phpMyAdmin like this: 
[image: table3]

However, when I call it with the keyid 2332 and the known password, it just returns NULL.

[image: table4]

I'm just asking this question because I want to know:
**Is my stored procedure correct?**

Because if it is, I know that the key I thought to be correct is actually wrong or I'm using it in a wrong way. Since this is the first time I'm writing a SQL procedure I have no idea if the fault is in the first reason or the second reason :/.

(Server data: "Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution", "Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.19")

EDIT: Running the query in the comments gives apperently a blob as result, but with no download link! It does however simplify the query the query greatly and I don't even have to create a procedure now for this.

[image]

Comment: What result do you have when running this:
`SELECT AES_Descrypt(blahb, 'PLACE_HERE_YOUR_KEY') from fyle where keeid = 2332`;

Comment: Screenshots are really confusing the issue here. Can you paste in the query you're trying as plain text?

Comment: @tadman I'm all doing this through the Web-UI of phpMyAdmin, copy-pasted the procedure as I showed, then executing the procedure with the shown input parameters. (absolute sql-newbie here)

Comment: @ConsiderMe: thanks, that singe-line query looks nicer than what I'm trying with procedures! post updated.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I believe this answers your question. You don't need a procedure for that as you've noticed yourself. I'm not using PHPMyAdmin so I can't answer why you don't see the download link - maybe it's designed that way. You can also convert the returned value to a string. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762956/phpmyadmin-show-blob-fields-as-text

Comment: @ConsiderMe THANK YOU, that was the solution. In the options, I expanded it to "Full Text" and "Well Known Binary", which gave me a very long hex string, then I wrote a program to convert that hexstring to a binary file again, and everything worked just fine. If you post your single-line query and the link to the phpMyAdmin solution, I'll mark it is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a procedure to get the decrypted blob. Call a function within a select statement instead:

```
SELECT AES_Decrypt(blahb, 'PLACE_HERE_YOUR_KEY') from fyle where keeid = 2332
```

Showing the `blob` field as `text` in PHPMyAdmin is pretty straightforward and has already been covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762956/phpmyadmin-show-blob-fields-as-text).